# PHP Replace any repeated letters with less number of letters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I would like to reduce a sequence of the same 5 repeating numbers or letters to a sequence of the same 2 repeating numbers or letters.

> i.e aaaaa => aa

**Problem:**

I am unsure on what parttern to put in the `preg_replace()` parameters.

**Example:**

```
preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}/','/[a-zA-Z0-9]{2}/',$str);
```

Any Ideas about this ? :)

Comment: Your question is unclear, when you speak about repeated letters, do you mean the same letter "aaaaa" or only five consecutive letters "abcde"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a capture group and a backreference:

```
$str = preg_replace('~([a-zA-Z0-9])\1{4}~', '$1$1', $str);
```

or

```
$str = preg_replace('~([a-zA-Z0-9])\1\K\1{3}~', '', $str);
```

details pattern 1:

```
~                # pattern delimiter
(                # open the capture group 1
    [a-zA-Z0-9] 
)                # close the capture group 1
\1{4}            # backreference: repeat 4 times the content of the capture group 1
~
```

In the replacement string `$1` refers to the content of the capture group 1. *(as `\1` in the pattern)*

The second pattern is not really different, it use only the `\K` feature that removes all on the left from the match result. With this trick, you don't need to put the two letters in the replacement string since they are preserved. Only the last 3 letters are replaced.

Comment: what does the backrefrence mean here ? 

and what about $1$1.. what does this too mean ?

Comment: Thanks ... this works fine but can you explain that regex to get it

Comment: @HasanZohdy enter the keyword(s) in google and it will tell you. Show research effort if others already provide the correct answer.

Comment: Big Thanks Pal for this explaination :)

Comment: What program/website breaks down and comments regex explanation like this? I see enough people do it, I assume that program is involved.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with simple string functions and basic programming constructs:

```
$str="aaaaa 11111 bbbbb";
for($ascii=32;$ascii<=126;$ascii++) {
  $char=chr($ascii);
  $charcharcharcharchar=$char . $char . $char . $char . $char;
  $charchar=$char . $char;
  if(strpos($str, $charcharcharcharchar) !== FALSE) { $str=str_replace($charcharcharcharchar, $charchar, $str); }
}
```